# How to place view to unusual place

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout, margin

I need to divide screen on two equal vertical area's and at 43% heights must be placed three `TextViews`. One at left half of screen, one on right and one at center. I did that:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <View android:id="@+id/fakeView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" 
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="100"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/fakeView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="43">
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="24" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
             <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="80"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/fakeView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="43">
        </LinearLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="24" 
            android:gravity="center_vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="80"
                android:textSize="24sp"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_marginRight="14dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="33" >
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"
        android:textSize="24sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is an image which can explain what I want:

[image]

Overall, screen divided, left and right `TextViews` on their places(top margin is 43% of global `RelativeLayout`), but I can't place third `TextView` at center, between `textView1` and `textView2`.

I have only one idea:
Set top margin for `TextView2` programmatically, using `View.getHeight()` and `LayoutParams`. But in `OnCreate` Activity is *Stopped* and I can't use this method until Activity will be *Resumed*. And only after Activity became *Resumed* I can replace `TextView2`. I think it is a bad way.

P/S global `RelativeLayout` is only a small part of screen
P/SS Right and left part of this layout will be clickable, so I can't draw another `LinearLayout` with empty layout for divide and one TextView below, because in this case left and right side became unclickable.

So, how can be `TextView2` placed between `TextView1` and `TextView3`?

Comment: Provide a link to your image (even on dropbox), whatever. We'll put it on your question. I think it's not difficult to achieve the strructure you want only by using an xml layout, without having to mess with code... Just let's visualize it.

Comment: @Tobor I hope that normal way which use only xml layout is exist, but all my ways are monstrous and awkward.

Comment: So, let me try. Maybe, my way works. But I have to SEE what you mean... 1 picture is worth 100000000 words.

Comment: @Tobor Here [way1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wcovofddbxxq2z6/img1.png)  [way2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mblrwht7zm11czk/img2.png). Way 1 is uncomfortable for user, way 2 is uncomfortable for me

Comment: Which one do you want? 1 or 2?

Comment: @Tobor I don't want both. Both i can write, i understand how to do them, but way 1 will be not accepted by testers and way 2 have some problems with background, speed and so on. I want to find a better way.

Comment: So you don't want any. Could you draw me one that satisfies your requirements?

Comment: @Tobor I placed link to image in my question. [Here it is](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zgtok54bkht5npr/img.png)

Comment: OK, now give me a bit of time - I'm going out for half an hour and will come back. Then it should take me about 10 minutes to prepare the xml- ;)

Comment: I'm back. Is 43%, 14%, 43% **mandatory**? or am I free to set the central part's height to fit its contents? Do you need it without title and statusbar, I presume?

Comment: @Tobor. 43% - it's empty area between top edge of `Layout` and top edge of `TextView`. `TextView` height can be set to `wrap_content`.  43% come from size of global Layout, so height of statusbar and title ignored

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See if this thing matches your needs.
It's very easy and lightweight, but I din't take in account **percentages**.

The result looks like:

[image]

The xml is:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="#f0f"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and in onCreate() I have:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Make this activity, full screen
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    // Hide the Title bar of this activity screen
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

    setContentView(R.layout.mannimar);
}
```

If percentages are **compulsory**, I'll then study something else.

**[EDIT]**

OK, so this is the result:

[image]

and this is the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#f00"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#00f"
            android:layout_weight="1"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        >
        <!-- Spacewaster: Top -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_weight="43"
        />
        <!-- The TextViews -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="14"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt1"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="#00f"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="#f0f"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txt3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_margin="0dp"
                android:background="#f00"
                android:layout_weight="1"
            />
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- Spacewaster: Bottom -->
        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:background="#0000"
            android:layout_weight="43"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, unfortunately percentages are compulsory. If i change `android:layout_centerHorizontal ="true"` to `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` in `TextView2` and move `TextView1` and `TextView3` i will get same result. But this idiotic design idea crash all my plans :)

Comment: OK, relax, let me see what I can do with percentages... give another 10 mins.

Comment: Ok, but if i think right, big `ImageView`s will be uncklicable? `LinearLayout` with `TextView` lay over layout which divide screen. I wrote in question, that this variant is not that i need. Am i wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand you wanted the big areas clickable. And I tought you said that the last one was the definitive layout. Now, to pass through the layers, you have to make them smaller. So the Views can be 1dp wide and the LinearLayout as wide as the inner one (240 dp). But still you will have an UNCLICKABLE COLUMN IN THE MIDDLE... So, the first design is probably the better one. Even without perfect percentages. OR, having the first one, you then have to modify it via code...

Comment: Ok, i make this 1 px column clickable and it will make the same with right part. Or it will remain unclickable. I will decide it later :)  Thank you. But sorry, i can't vote up your answer, because i have only 3 reputation and for voting up i need at least 15 :(

Comment: NO. The column in the middle is 240 dp wide, not 1 px wide... Or the TextViews will disappear

Comment: Oh, yea, i understand now. Unfortunately Layout is a rectangle :)

Comment: Overall I will use code to set the height and margin. Or I will beat my designer until he not place this text fields at center :)